# What's wrong with my XHTML file in earliers internet explorer, infinite loop, nothing is rendered?

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, xhtml, xml-namespaces

What's wrong with structure below, in earliers internet explorer (5.5/6/7/8) the browser start a infinite loop, and nothing is rendered?

as you can see that the `p` tags has a prefixes, it's important for my project, the content of the body element must be inserted with a server side language, each **HTML** fragment could be sent from a different users, in fact some fragments could containe the same **id** name or **css** **class** name, so that's why i"m using XMLNS to make a distinction between each fragment...

index.php

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/xml'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:aa="zz" xmlns:ee="rr">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
            p{background: #0000ff;}
        aa\:p{background: #00ff00;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <aa:p>aaa</aa:p>
    <ee:p>aaa</ee:p>
</body>
</html>
```

xslt.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`?

Comment: sorry :) because the php file serve the header content-type, maybe that's it that causes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your DTD at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

What's probably happening is that IE's XSLT processor is searching for this DTD definition and then hanging somehow.

It appears to work if you delete it from the PHP file and add it to the XSLT, and in fact, this is the only way to actually have the DTD in the output of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
              doctype-system=" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>

  <!-- ... -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd also suggest adding this to your XSLT to strip out the xml-stylesheet PI from the output:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')" />
```